# How to format pivot table numbers with a thousands seperator and negative numbers in brackets?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to format my negative numbers in "Accounting" format, i.e. with brackets and a comma as a thousands sepertor. For example, I would like to format -1000000 as (1,000,000).

I was able to format my numbers (in a pivot table) with a thousand separator or with brackets for negative numbers, but not both.

- this formats the numbers in a pivot table (alias pt) with a thousands separator:

  ```
  pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
  print(pt)
  ```
- this formats the numbers in a pivot table with brackets for negative numbers:

  ```
  formatter = lambda x: '(%s)' % str(x)[1:] if x < 0 else str(x)
  pd.options.display.float_format = formatter
  pt
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def my_formatter(x):
    if x < 0:
        return '({:,.0f})'.format(-x)
    return '{:,.0f}'.format(x)

pd.options.display.float_format = my_formatter
```

Example:

```
pd.DataFrame([10000000., -20000000.])
#             0
#0   10,000,000
#1 (20,000,000)
```